Best way to reset a DbContext before calling SaveChanges when using EnableRetryOnFailure?
I have an operation handler that modifies a series of entities. Each of these modifications can throw an exception that forces me to cancel all previous changes and mark an entity as faulted.
Consider the pseudocode below.
try
{
   ChangeAnEntity(db);
   
   ChangeAnotherEntity(db);
   
   CreateSomeEntities(db);
   
   ExecuteMethodThatCanThrow();
   
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch
{
   SetAnEntityAsFaulted(db);
    
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

Initially I thought about using transactions but user-created transactions are not supported when resilient SQL connections are enabled via "EnableRetryOnFailure".
await using var transaction = await db.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

try
{
   ...
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch
{
   await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);

   SetAnEntityAsFaulted(db);
    
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

I got the following exception (but for PostgreSQL)

System.InvalidOperationException: The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

I promptly asked ChatGPT and it suggested me using the following snippet. It seems correct, but I wonder if there is a better solution.
try
{
   ...
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch
{
   ResetChanges(db);

   SetAnEntityAsFaulted(db);
    
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void ResetChanges(DbContext db)
{
    var changedEntries = db.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                           .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                           .ToList();

    foreach (var entry in changedEntries)
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Modified:
                entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;

            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                break;

            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                break;
        }
    }
}

Ideally I just want to reset the Unit of Work and set my entity as faulted.

mark an entity as faulted - what does it mean? Usually db.ChangeTracker.Clear() is enough to reset context.

In your Dbcontext add the following code:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Connction string",
                    npgsqlOptions => npgsqlOptions.ExecutionStrategy(d => new NpgsqlRetryingExecutionStrategy(d)));

}

this Line is important to be added to the OnConfiguring method or Program.cs file:
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("connectionString",
                            npgsqlOptions => npgsqlOptions.ExecutionStrategy(d => new NpgsqlRetryingExecutionStrategy(d)));

Then Change your method to this:
public async Task HandleOperationAsync()
{
    var strategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

    await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

        try
        {
            // Perform your operations
            ChangeAnEntity();
            ChangeAnotherEntity();
            CreateSomeEntities();
            ExecuteMethodThatCanThrow();

            // Save changes and commit the transaction
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Rollback the transaction
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();

            // Set an entity as faulted and save changes
            SetAnEntityAsFaulted();
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            throw; // Re-throw the exception to propagate it
        }
    });
}

private void ExecuteMethodThatCanThrow()
{
    throw new Exception("Simulated exception");
}


Use db.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy() to get the execution strategy configured for the context.

By following these steps, you can verify that the provided solution works correctly in your environment.
I created a project and tested it with my local PostgreSQL and it works smoothly. Tell me if there is a problem with it
I hope it could be helpful :)

Thanks for your reply. I'm using the default setup from the Aspire PostgreSQL component. Is your setup equivalent?

According to the ‘Npgsql’ , is an open source ADO.NET Data Provider for ‘PostgreSQL’ and implemented on EF, I implemented this to use EF features
